# Bind9 on 22.04 server - many no valid signature found in syslog

Tags: dns, bind

I know just enough about this to be dangerous.  I have bind9 running on 22.04 Server.  I have noticed many entries in the syslog from named such as this....

```
Aug 23 16:40:39 homesvr01 named[29547]: validating sync.adtelligent.com/CNAME: no valid signature found
Aug 23 16:40:39 homesvr01 named[29547]: validating sync.vertamedia.com/CNAME: no valid signature found
Aug 23 16:47:06 homesvr01 named[29547]: message repeated 3 times: [ validating sync.vertamedia.com/CNAME: no valid signature found]
Aug 23 16:47:35 homesvr01 named[29547]: validating plex.tv/A: no valid signature found
```

However when I run dig on the sites logged it returns an answer.

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28686
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;plex.tv.                       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
plex.tv.                19      IN      A       52.212.244.29
plex.tv.                19      IN      A       54.229.5.9

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 23 16:50:37 EDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

named.conf.local...

```
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "bender.int" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/forward.bender.int.db";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "71.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/reverse.bender.int.db";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

named.conf.options...

```
acl "trusted" {
        192.168.71.0/24;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        listen-on { 192.168.71.202; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

  
};
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed with this.  These messages are constantly hitting my syslog.  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The message is only an information, not an error, that the DNSKEY RRset of the requested site is not secure. Bind9 then falls back to insecurity proof. An example log of this validation you can find at https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/2680#note_211560. The only real solution I can see, is that the owner of the DNS domain should register it with a valid signature.